# MATLAB MILP optimization Problem with summation in objective function as well as in equations subject to

Tags: matlab, optimization

There are 3 variables L, M, H, and one OBJECTIVE FUNCTION

Mixed Integer Linear Programming  problem I am stuck in making an Array A[] and B[] with summation for intlinprog()

I have read this on MATLAB [forum](https://in.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html) how to use `intlinprog()` and it was easy to make array A easily for equation with no summation

***HOW TO BUILD A[] for [image: formula]***

```
 Minimize OBJ=sum(PCL.*L+PCM.*M+PCH.*H);  // How to make this type of array
   X-CL.*L-CM.*M-CH.*H=0;
   sum(RM(j)*L(j))<=R(k);
```

What I did or tried:

```
PCL=[50.7,56.8,56.4]=PCM=PCH;  %FOR SHORTENING QUESTION I WROTE SAME

SP=[0.975,0.975,0.975];

RM=[0.948,0.9432,0.949];

R=[500,500];


%STUCK AT THIS POINT
%L M H
%BELOW LINE IS WRONG HOW SHOULD I BUILD A and B

A=[1 0 -100000 0 0 0; 0 -1 0 1 0 0;0 1 0 0 0 1;RM1 0 0 0 0 0;RM2 0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 IL IM IH];

B=[0;0;1;R(1);R(2);Budget];

OBJ=[PCL PCM PCH];

lb=[0 0 0];

ub=[inf inf inf];

[x,fval]=intlinprog(OBJ,intcon,A,B,Aeq,Beq,lb,ub);
```

Comment: I am afraid that this question lacks clarity. It the equation suggests that the variables `L`, `M`, and `H` matrices, with which `intlinprog` wouldn't work. If they are scalars, it should work easily; but the code you have posted doesn't seem to have much to do with your equation...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
clc;clear;
tic
PCL=PCM=PCH=[n data];

CL=CM=CH=[n data];

IL=IM=IH=[n data];

SP=[n data];


RM1=[n data];
RM2=[n  data];

R=[500,500];
Budget=1000;
ZN=zeros(n,1);
ON=ones(n,1);
F(1,:)=[-SP';ZN;ZN;PCL';PCM';PCH'];
A(1,:)=[ON;ZN;-1000000*ON;ZN;ZN;ZN];
A(2,:)=[ZN;-1*ON;ZN;ON;ZN;ZN];
A(3,:)=[ZN;ON;ZN;ZN;ZN;ON];
A(4,:)=[RM1';ZN;ZN;ZN;ZN;ZN];
A(5,:)=[RM2';ZN;ZN;ZN;ZN;ZN];
A(6,:)=[ZN;ZN;ZN;IL';IM';IH'];
B=[0;0;1;R(1);R(2);Budget];
intcon=(55:162);
lb=zeros(1,324);
ub=inf(1,324);
ub(55:162)=1;
Aeq(1,:)=[ON;ZN;ZN;-1*CL';-1*CM';-1*CH'];
Aeq(2,:)=[ZN;ZN;-1*ON;ON;ON;ON];
Beq=[0;0];
[x,FVAL,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT]=intlinprog(F,intcon,A,B,Aeq,Beq,lb,ub);
FVAL=-1*FVAL;
X=x(1:n);
Y=x(55:108);
Z=x(109:162);
L=x(163:216);
M=x(217:270);
H=x(271:324);
TOTAL_TIME=toc;
```